# How can I get a file's group ID (GID) in Go?

Tags: file, go

`os.Stat()` returns a [`FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) object, which has a `Sys()` method that returns an `Interface{}` with no methods.

Though I am able to `fmt.Printf()` it to "see" the "Gid", I am unable to access "Gid" programmatically.

How do I retrieve the "Gid" of a file here?

```
file_info, _ := os.Stat(abspath)
file_sys := file_info.Sys()
fmt.Printf("File Sys() is: %+v", file_sys)
```

Prints:

```
File Sys() is: &{Dev:31 Ino:5031364 Nlink:1 Mode:33060 Uid:1616 Gid:31 X__pad0:0 Rdev:0 Size:32 Blksize:32768 Blocks:0 Atim:{Sec:1564005258 Nsec:862700000} Mtim:{Sec:1563993023 Nsec:892256000} Ctim:{Sec:1563993023 Nsec:893251000} X__unused:[0 0 0]}
```

Note: I do not need a portable solution, it just has to work on Linux (notable because [`Sys()`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14753) is known to be flaky).

Possibly related: [Convert interface{} to map in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185916/convert-interface-to-map-in-golang)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf) module showed that the data type for `Sys()`'s return is `*syscall.Stat_t`, so this seems to work to get the Gid of a file as a string:

```
file_info, _ := os.Stat(abspath)
file_sys := file_info.Sys()
file_gid := fmt.Sprint(file_sys.(*syscall.Stat_t).Gid)
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: This is how you can do it. You could use the special form of type assertion in case someone runs this on a platform where this fails: `if stat, ok := file_sys.(*syscall.Stat_t); ok { fmt.Println(stat.Gid) }`.

Comment: Or alternatively you may directly call [`syscall.Stat()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Stat) which returns [`*syscall.Stat_t`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Stat_t) but that is not available on all target OSes (e.g. on Window).