# Cast interface to concrete type - type switch

Tags: go, interface, casting

I am looking for a way to cast an interface into the concrete type to save a lot of source code.

The initial situation are two functions of a webserver handler. They differ only in that one function decodes an array of structs and the other decodes a single struct and stores it in the database. The functions which have to be called for saving are identical depending on the type.

To decide whether an array or a struct is passed, it is tried to cast the interface into the type and then to pass this appropriately as a parameter of the function. Similar as it is described in the [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) and in the stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186057/7652996).

However, I do not get the concrete type as expected and the program always runs into the default section. What am I doing wrong or have I not taken into account?

These are the outputs of the default section:

```
# interface is a struct
... or a single repository struct: map[string]interface{}

# interface is an array of structs
... or a single repository struct: []interface{}
```

Below is the source code with the functions

```golang
func (rh *RouteHandler) AddOrUpdateRepository(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    repository := new(types.Repository)
    rh.addOrUpdateRepositories(rw, req, repository)
}

func (rh *RouteHandler) AddOrUpdateRepositories(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    repositories := make([]*types.Repository, 0)
    rh.addOrUpdateRepositories(rw, req, repositories)
}

func (rh *RouteHandler) addOrUpdateRepositories(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, v interface{}) {
    defer req.Body.Close()

    switch req.Header.Get("Content-Type") {
    case "application/xml":
        xmlDecoder := xml.NewDecoder(req.Body)
        err := xmlDecoder.Decode(&v)
        if err != nil {
            rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to decode repositories or repository")
            rh.ulogger.Error("Failed to decode repositories or repository: %v", err)
            return
        }
    case "application/json":
        fallthrough
    default:
        jsonDecoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
        err := jsonDecoder.Decode(&v)
        if err != nil {
            rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to decode repositories or repository")
            rh.ulogger.Error("Failed to decode repositories or repository: %v", err)
            return
        }
    }

    var err error
    switch x := v.(type) {
    case map[string]*types.Repository:
        for _, repository := range x {
            err = rh.manager.AddOrUpdateRepository(context.Background(), repository)
        }
    case *types.Repository:
        err = rh.manager.AddOrUpdateRepository(context.Background(), x)
    case map[string][]*types.Repository:
        for i := range x {
            for j := range x[i] {
                err = rh.manager.AddOrUpdateRepository(context.Background(), x[i][j])
            }
        }
    case []*types.Repository:
        err = rh.manager.AddOrUpdateRepository(context.Background(), x...)
    case nil:
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to cast interface")
        rh.ulogger.Error("Failed to cast interface. Interface is a type of nil")
        return
    default:
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to cast interface")
        rh.ulogger.Error("Failed to cast interface. Interface does not match onto an array of repositories or a single repository struct: %T", x)
        return
    }

    if err != nil {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to add repositories or repository")
        rh.ulogger.Error("Failed to add repositories or repository: %v", err)
        return
    }
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

}
```

[image]

Comment: Note: Go doesn't have type casting _at all_. What you're after is a type conversion.

Comment: "one function decodes an array of structs" -- Another terminology note: That's not an array. It's a slice.

Comment: You're probably trying to assert to the wrong type. To make debugging easier, consider adding something like this to your `default` case:  `fmt.Fprintf(rw, "Failed to assert type %T", v)`, which will show you the actual type encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Simplified a bit.)

You have a function with the following signature:

```golang
func addOrUpdateRepositories(v interface{})
```

and then you call it like this:

```golang
repository := new(types.Repository)
addOrUpdateRepositories(repository)
```

and like this:

```golang
repositories := make([]*types.Repository, 0)
addOrUpdateRepositories(repositories)
```

In the first call, the concrete type of the value stored in `v` will be `*types.Repository` (as `new` returns a pointer to the allocated value) and in the second call the concrete type of the value stored in `v` will be `[]*types.Repository`—because that's what `make` was told to create.

Now you do a type-switch on `v`, which reads:

```golang
switch x := v.(type) {
case map[string]*types.Repository:
case map[string][]*types.Repository:
case nil:
default:
}
```

Leaving aside the case that if you do not call `addOrUpdateRepositories` passing it a `nil` `v` which cannot happen in the snippet from your question, the `switch` will always pick the default branch because the type of the concrete value stored in `v` is never `map[string]*types.Repository` or `map[string][]*types.Repository`.

I am not sure why you fail to see this, so probably you should refine your question or may be try to clear up your confusion in a comment to my answer?

---

Another shot in the dark: type conversions (note that Go does not have type casts, as @Flimzy pointed out) and type switches in Go do not actually change the underlying representation of the value they operate on—except for the limited set of ("everyone expects this") cases such as type-converting a `float64` to `int64`, which are precisely documented.

So you cannot take a `[]*types.Repository` (a slice of pointers to values of type `types.Repository`) and somehow force it "to become" `map[string][]*types.Repository`: that'd be a nonsensical thing to do for a number of reasons, with the most glaring being this: if you were writing the Go compiler, how would you carry out such a "type cast"? Suppose you were to really allocate a map, but then which key in that map should have been assigned the original (source) slice?  What about type-converting a `[]*types.Repository` to `struct {foo []*types.Repository; bar []*types.Repository}`?

Comment: I already used `*types.Repository` and `[]*types.Repository` as case statement, but the program always runs into default. Via `%T` I get the type of the interface. I get for `*types.Repository` `[]interface` and for a slice of `*types.Repository` `map[string]interface{}`. I can't explain why it still gives interface as type after a cast.

Comment: @VolkerRaschek, you than have a logic error in your (whole) program. A heavily dumbed-down [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to display there's really no magic: https://play.golang.org/p/47LM45kMIiO

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this out in a small project. That's why I was totally irritated, because there it worked. I have now found that it is because of the source code to decode json or xml. After decoding the interface v just doesn't match as expected. Here is a screenshot of the program running in the default section after decoding json. 

I have recreated the whole thing: https://play.golang.org/p/Z2aCIHZAPk9

Comment: I must copy the interface before it will be passed to the decoder. Otherwise it is broken: https://play.golang.org/p/YqnM26biKrV

Comment: @VolkerRaschek, OK, I see what happens. I'll try to post another answer in a short while.

Comment: @VolkerRaschek, to get you going quickier, here's a working version: <https://play.golang.org/p/jSC3dFm9uXM>. Note how the variables are allocated and passed to the function and also note how `v` is passed to `json.Decode` "as is"—without taking its address.